# High voltage to low voltage in ps/nanosecond time (Zener/opamp?)

Tags: operational-amplifier, high-voltage, zener, high-frequency, high-speed

So I have a signal that goes from 0 to ~800volts in 30ns. I would like to use this signal to trigger a camera (input impedance of 50ohm) which takes a max of 10 volts and requires the rise time to be 1ns for this 10 volts.
I tried a 10 volt zener diode which works... but delays the signal a lot (not sure why) so I get 10 volts in 8ns instead of 1ns. [People said zeners are made for DC and not so much for high frequencies, so maybe thats why]

I then thought of using attenuators to make the signal go from 0 to 10 volts (instead of 800V) in 30ns then use an opamp as a comparator with a 10volt DC battery connected to +Vs and Ref, Vin-, -Vs connected to the negative side of the battery. (and ofc the main signal going to Vin+) 
Since different opamps got different operating frequencies and slew rates I got this one:  THS3491IDDAT
Which got a  320 MHz operating frequency and  8 kV/us slew rate

[image: circuit used]

However, I was getting weird results that I wasnt able to understand and shortly after multiple legs of the op amp broke, so I wasn't able to capture the output signal

Here is the input signal which is attenuated using 38dB (div 80) [time scale is 10ns/div and voltage scale is 10v/div

[image: input signal]

Was I doing something wrong? or is there an easier circuit to use? Any recommendation for other opamps that are easy to handle? (this one was tiny)

The source is a Rogowski coil with a resistance of 4ohm and inductance of 1.4e-7 H. (1 turn coil).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the output impedance of your source? Which Zener did you use, and what value of resistors? What is the minimum your camera can trigger on?

Comment: You have a signal source that provides you with \$\approx 30\frac{\text{kV}}{\mu\text{s}}\$? What's the output impedance of your signal?

Comment: @Ale..chenski The source is a Rogowski coil which got a resistance of 4ohms but not sure about its impedance. (calculated the inducatance to be about 1.4e-7 H)
I used 1N5925B for the zener diode which is 10volts and 3 watt.
the camera can trigger with 5 volts and max 10volt.

Comment: @jonk well its not 30kv/us per say, it only goes to 800volts in 30ns then goes to 0 after.
Not entirly sure about the source impedance, its a Rogowski coil with 1 turn and about 4ohms resistance (calculated induactance of 1.4e-7 H)

Comment: First rule about using op amps as comparators: Don't use op amps as comparators. Get a real (very fast) comparator. Second, do not try to use floating, dead bug construction for nsec response times. You need a proper ground plane and good construction techniques.

Comment: One nanosecond is quite a short time. Many of us surely are curious what camera needs and why it needs so sharp edge. Can you reveal it?

Comment: Zener diodes have relatively high capacitance. Use a high speed diode to a 10V source (which can be a zener diode).

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast So opamps aren't reliable? thanks for the suggestion, I wasn't aware that comparators existed (I thought we had to use opamps)
Will work on that. If you have any specific component on mind please let me know. I'm in the process of searching for one right now.

Comment: @user287001 so its for triggering a streak camera, which is a camera that can do time resolved images. It does like picosecond time resolution.

Comment: @DCMed i have read that it can make  3D imaging by taking so fast series of photos that every photo contains only one distance resolution element. The light comes from the camera. Right?

Comment: @τεκ So the 800 volts go into a high speed diode to a 10volt zener diode? 
something like this : https://imgur.com/sSf0msp ?

Comment: @user287001 The light comes from the source not from the camera. the light hits a gold foil, which converts the photons to electrons, then using high voltage plates as in the old TV's, they control the electrons, then these electrons hit a phosphor screen and get converted back to photons.

Comment: You said shortly after your test multiple legs broke off the op amp. for the type of frequencies you're dealing with for those edges, you probably need this on a PCB with plenty of bypass capacitors and a good supply. If you had this bread boarded or wires soldered onto a package, there's no way you're going to have clean edges and I would expect the ringing that you showed.

Comment: @DCMed - Since op amps are intended to operate in their linear range, with the inputs very close to each other, they do not handle large input differentials very well, and they can be very slow to recover from such a condition. Comparators, on the other hand, do handle the condition gracefully. The problem there is that not many will drive a grounded 50 ohm load directly, so you'll need an output buffer.

Comment: @DCMed like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7YgX.png (1 ohm resistor probably unnecessary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKJHvj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: +1. To add, I have some feelings that the camera triggers from a regular 5-V TTL signal. Which is 2.4 V.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you need is a "capacitance speed-up."

Take a look at the following. Blue is the source pulse / 100 (so it fits on the scale.) Red is what a resistor + Zener would output. Green is what is output if a "capacitance speed-up" is used.

[image: LTspice simulation of a capacitor speed-up circuit.]

Note that the 1N755 is only a 500mW device, and the peak pulse from C1 into it approaches 650mW. Not really a problem for "a few" photos, but it couldn't be run like this continuously. Also note that the speed-up creates a nearly -1v tail... careful.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously have some high cost instruments. I wouldn't compromise their life span with experimental add-on circuits. Get an industrially built unit. High Speed Pulse Generators (search for them) are available as modules and as laboratory instruments.

If you want to build one, you can use Step Recovery Diodes to generate fast rising voltages. Here's one principle:

https://www.overunityresearch.com/index.php?PHPSESSID=bgbfjuvodm8ekjgusgka0r4ed6&topic=1556.msg26264#msg26264

The idea is to use the sudden reverse conductivity stopping of a step recovery diode to break the current in an inductor and thus genrating a pulse.